# REST complaining "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"

Tags: java, rest, websphere

I have a REST project and would like to call the `EJB` method in the local interface in `EJB` project but seems like it is complaining `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. In REST project, I have java build path referenced to `EJB` project.

**EJB- SB_UtilityBean.java**

```
package com.belsize.sb;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless(name = "SB_Utility") 
public class SB_UtilityBean implements SB_UtilityLocal {
    public String getKeyid() {
        String _key_id = (new Uuid()).toString();
        return _key_id;
    }
}
```

**EJB- SB_UtilityLocal.java**

```
package com.belsize.sb;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface SB_UtilityLocal {
    public String getKeyid();
}
```

**Rest- web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <display-name></display-name> 
  <servlet>
    <display-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS REST Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Rest- WEB-INF\lib**

```
jersey-bundle-1.19.1.jar
```

**Rest- AndroidsResource.java**

```
package pagecode;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import com.belsize.sb.SB_UtilityLocal;

@Stateless
@Path("androids")
public class AndroidsResource {

    @EJB
    private SB_UtilityLocal UTIL;

    @GET
    public String getKeyid() {
        String _LOC = "[REST: getKeyid]";
        System.out.println(_LOC + "1.0");

        return UTIL.getKeyid();
    }
}
```

I tried to access http://localhost:9080/BelsizeRest/jaxrs/androids
But getting the following errors.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.belsize.sb.SB_UtilityLocal
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:688)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:667)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:119)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
    ... 45 more
```

I am using IBM WebSphere Application Server Express V8.0. Not sure if I missed out anything?

Comment: Where are AndroidsResource, SB_Local, and SB_UtilityBean packaged in the EAR?  The (NoClassDefFoundError?) exception stack trace suggests AndroidsResource is packaged in a WAR in an EAR, but it also suggests that SB_Local at least is not packaged in the EAR.

Comment: @BrettKail Hi, currently, my EAR (EJB, Web) and REST war are deployed separately. I think I might be missing some steps on the packaging before deploy.